# Converters not executing with DataView

Tags: .net, wpf, inotifypropertychanged, dataview

I'm using a grid control from DevExpress. I've binded the grid to a DataView:

```
m_dvResponses = New DataView(...)
m_dvResponses.Sort = "SEQUENCENUMBER"

GridResponses.ItemsSource = m_dvResponses
```

Everything seems to work fine. When the underlying data changes, the grid updates automatically, so that's good.

Problem is that I color some of the cells using a Converter on a specific column:

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="AGENCYNAME" CellStyle="{StaticResource AgencyCellStyle}"/>

<Style x:Key="AgencyCellStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {dxgt:GridRowThemeKey ResourceKey=CellStyle}}" TargetType="{x:Type dxg:CellContentPresenter}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="8,0,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding Path=RowData.Row, Converter={StaticResource AgencyBackgroundColorConverter}, ConverterParameter=AGENCY}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=RowData.Row, Converter={StaticResource AgencyForegroundColorConverter}, ConverterParameter=AGENCY}" />
</Style>
```

When the data changes, the value is updated, but the converter doesn't seem to execute. The converter only executes when the grid paints itself.

[image: Before ...]

[image: After ...]

Notice how the new "p1" didn't color itself since the Converter didn't fire on the update.

My question is: Does a DataView trigger a converter when data gets updated? Are converters dependant on objects that implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: As far as I know, converters are executed when a binding changes, and yes, I believe WPF's data binding is triggered via INotifyPropertyChanged or dependency properties. It's difficult to help you without seeing the specific code involved, though. I think if you edit your question to include some samples, you'll stand a better chance at getting an answer.

Comment: Brandon, I've updated my post  :)